# Javascript form queries

Tags: javascript, forms, http, post, request

How can I use javascript to set the attributes of a preexisting form and then execute the form to receive a response?

Basically, there is a search directory that I want to input emails into and receive an output of the department that person works in.

Here is the form.

```
<form name="frm" action="/directory/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="text" size="30" name="search" value="" />
   <button id="submit" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var form = document.getElementById("formID"); // get form
form.setAttribute("action" /* desired attribute */, "url.com"); // set attribute
form.submit(); // submit form
```